# display values after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a form in html with two submit buttons either one is enabled. if user is filling the form submit is enabled and the other button is diasbled.
when user clicks submit button other button gets enabled and displays all the field values with read only .when the 2nd button is clicked values are enterd in databse, using **jquery** or **javascript**
 is it possible

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, the first button does not actually submit the form?

```
$("#firstbutton").click(function() {
    $("#myForm input").attr("readonly", "readonly"); //this makes the input fields readonly

    $("#secondbutton").attr("disabled","disabled"; //this enable the second button

    $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); //this disables the #firstbutton
}
```

Make sure that:

- On page load, the second button is already disabled.
- If you have dropdownlists in your form, you'll have to set those readonly as well, as they are not `<input>` but `<select>` items.
- the firstbutton should not be of `type="submit"`, it should either be of `type="button"` or be a `<button>` tag instead.
- Your secondbutton can be a regular submit button, nothing fancy required. As long as your form posts to the correct actionlink, the form will be submitted fine.
- Never use `disabled` attribute on your input fields. If you do, the form submit will ignore these fields and not post them as intended. You're already doing it right by using readonly.

Comment: i have a doubt.. will be the values displayed back

Comment: flater may i know hw to do

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $myForm = $(this);

    $myForm.find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $myForm.find('input#other-button').attr('enabled','enabled');


    //do a $.post request
    $.post('/path/to/my-file.php',
           $myForm.serialize(),
           function(data){
             // make something after the post is complete
             $myForm.find("input[type=text]").attr('readonly','readonly');
           },
           'json');
  });
});
```

Comment: i have a doubt.. will be the values displayed back